# Hidden, absolutely positioned, elements cause scroll to top on unhide

Tags: jquery, html, css

Apologies for the garbage title. I am building a few menu views that I want to only show on user input. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52ho0evc/1/) - the example is basic but it all functions pretty much how I would like except that if the user is scrolled some ways down on the page, when showing a `view` it scrolls the page to the top.

Any ideas how I can make the panes just show anywhere in the doc, no matter how far up or down the user is scrolled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding `overflow: hidden` to the `#main` element along with `height: 100%`, not exactly sure why, but that was causing the the page to scroll back to the top.

If I add the `overflow` to the `body` of the doc rather than the element, it accomplishes the same goal and causes the page not to scroll to the top; also I should have been using `fixed` elements rather than `absolute` I reckon.

[Here is an updated fiddle that works properly](http://jsfiddle.net/52ho0evc/3/).